# Regex Help needed for dinamic web url

Tags: javascript, regex

Need to check dynamic url using regex.

URL : /shop/1/products or /shop/23/products

Need to validate this url using regex

I am trying :

"/shop/[0-9]/products"

but did not work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you have multidigit numbers, you must use `+` iterator:

```
/\/shop\/\d+\/products/
```

If you want to get shop ID, you must use capture group.

```
var url = '/shop/23/products';
var regex = /\/shop\/(\d+)\/products/;
var shopId = url.match(regex)[1];

console.log(shopId);
```

Comment: Can you please help me to get shopId from that url using regex ?

Comment: @Bilash. Check my answer.